# Yet another curious incident in the flea circus

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, reachability

The ringmaster of a flea circus puts four fleas $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ on
four different points in the plane that form the corners of a square.

Whenever the ringmaster shouts *"Hop!"*, one of the four fleas jumps
over the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points) of the three other fleas to the mirror point on
the other side.
(In other words, a flea sitting in point $x$ may jump over the centroid
$y$ to the new point $z$, so that $y$ is the midpoint between $x$ and $z$.)

> **Question:** 
>   Is it possible that after a finite number of jumps, two of the fleas 
>   are simultaneously sitting on the same point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WLOG the fleas start at the corners of the unit square, with A at $(0,0)$, B at $(1,0)$, C at $(1,1)$, and D at $(0,1)$. I claim that after $n$ jumps, A will be at $(\frac{2a_1}{3^n},\frac{2a_2}{3^n})$, B will be at $(\frac{2b_1+1}{3^n},\frac{2b_2}{3^n})$, C will be at $(\frac{2c_1+1}{3^n},\frac{2c_2+1}{3^n})$, and D will be at $(\frac{2d_1}{3^n},\frac{2d_2+1}{3^n})$ for some integers $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,d_1,d_2$.

This is true in the starting position, with $n=0$. Now suppose that it is true after $n$ jumps, and A jumps next. The centroid of B, C, and D is $(\frac{2b_1+1+2c_1+1+2d_1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{2b_2+2c_2+1+2d_2+1}{3^{n+1}})$, and A ends up at the point $(\frac{4b_1+4c_1+4d_1+4-6a_1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{4b_2+4c_2+4d_2+4-6a_2}{3^{n+1}})=(\frac{2(2b_1+2c_1+2d_1+2-3a_1)}{3^{n+1}},\frac{2(2b_2+2c_2+2d_2+2-3a_2)}{3^{n+1}})$. Meanwhile, B stays at $(\frac{2b_1+1}{3^n},\frac{2b_2}{3^n})=(\frac{2(3b_1+1)+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{2(3b_2)}{3^{n+1}})$, and similarly for C and D.

Similar calculations show that if B, C, or D jumps instead of A, the claim still holds. Therefore it holds for all $n$.

Therefore no two fleas can ever be at the same position, because at least one coordinate's numerator would have to be both even and odd.

Comment: Very nice answer, clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I'm an idiot and answered the wrong question. Disregard.

No.

Call the initial positions of fleas A, B, C, and D `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(0,1)`, and `(1,1)` respectively. At any point in time, two fleas will be at a distance `(n,m)` away, where `n` and `m` are integers. Pivoting will move one flea a distance `(2n,2m)`. Flea A can only occupy the points `(2n,2m)`, flea B `(1+2n,2m)`, flea C `(2n,1+2m)`, and flea D `(1+2n,1+2m)`.

Comment: If flea D hops from your initial setup, it reaches the point $(-\tfrac13,-\tfrac13)$.

Comment: Yes I missread the question. I thought one flea was leapfrogging over another.